# Query changesets in TFS?

Tags: tfs, visual-studio-2013

Scenario if given 2 builds how do you view the changesets in the later build that aren't in he earlier. Are there any other ways to view and query changes...

Any thoughts appreciated

Comment: How are you triggering the builds?

Answer (score 0):

Since a label can be edited post hoc it's not possible to get the raw changesets between two labels. The diff commands will only give you file or folder differences.

However, if your builds label by changeset (or label the tip), which is a pretty typical scenario, then it is possible to look at the project history (by changeset) between the times when the two labels were created and build up a picture of what's changed between two points in time.

As a general rule, if your build system supports it, it's always helpful to put something useful in the label comments like 'Label xxxx created for build yyy at changeset zzz' which makes the label history a lot easier to interpret.

If you use Teambuild the build  template can be configured to give you a breakdown of changesets since the previous successful build label, which might save you some work going back retrospectively to find the information.